# Median of Gompertz Distribution is greater then the mean

Tags: probability

The Gompertz CDF is, $$F(x)=1-e^{-b(e^{ax}-1)}$$ for $a,b>0$. I found that $$E(X)=\frac{e^b}{a}\int\limits_1^\infty{\frac{e^{-bt}}{t}}dt$$ and the median is equal to $\frac{1}{a}\ln(1+\frac{\ln(2)} {b})$. Now I gotta prove that the median is greater then the expected value. I started by writing the log as an integral and so that what needs to be proved is

$$ \int\limits_1^{1+\frac{\ln(2)}{b}}{\frac{1}{t}} dt \geq\int\limits_1^\infty{\frac{e^{b(1-t)}}{t}}dt $$

the function on the right is obviously smaller then on left but the integral on the right is over more of the line, so I do not know how to proceed. I think a good strategy is to sandwich something between them but I cannot figure out what.